# How to set an Alarm using UiAutomator for google's clock?

Tags: java, android, testing, android-uiautomator

I need to set an alarm in Google's clock using UiAutomator, but UiAutomatorViewer does not retrieve information about the circle. Another solution could be using the ativity parameters, but I google it and I did not find that info.

[image: Setting an Alarm]

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of `UIAutomator`. Only when there is a corresponding `UI XML map` of the `UI Element` in the application, that object information can be obtained and processed.

There is a way of creating `UI Objects` dynamically which can't be read by `UIAutomatorviewer`, I believe above is such a case.

Comment: Sure, UiAutomator has limitations, and this is one of them. I'm using the Clock's activity to launch it, so, I would like to know if there is a way to send parameters to create a command to that activity. For example, for Chrome, you can do this `adb shell am start -n CHROMEACTIVITY -d www.google.com` and the result will be a Chrome screen loading Google. I am not pretty sure if Clock receive parameters.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.. But that depends on the framework of application(here Clock Apk) and not on UI Automator.. We can start playing with UI Automator API only if we can find node properties of the UI Object..

Comment: I need to interact with that circular interface in two of my tests. One of them to set an alarm, an the other one to verify if the phone can modify the hour. I used workarounds to solve them, maybe they would help to someone:
1. Setting an alarm with UiAutomator: Use GoogleNow with the command "Set an alarm XX YY" or "Set an alarm X minutes from now" and you will be able to set the alarm using Google now
2. If you want to verify/change hour using this circular interface, I solved getting the bounds of the object, after that use the `dragTo` command to the bounds (hour/minute).